# Transferring a String array to Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a method that can transfer an array into a Binary tree. I know the code is not right, I run it and hope it would show something that I can continue to fix it. But it just kept loading without any error or result. May anyone give me some advice, please!
Here is the BST class:

```
public class BSTNode {
    private String data;

    private BSTNode left;
    private BSTNode right;

    public BSTNode(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.right = null;
        this.left = null;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public BSTNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BSTNode left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public BSTNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BSTNode right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

And my method:

```
public BSTNode fromArray(String[] array, int start, int end) {
    int i = start;
    BSTNode root = new BSTNode(array[i]);
    BSTNode current = root;
    BSTNode parent = null;
    while (i <= end) {
        if (array[i].compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
            parent = current;
            current.setLeft(current); //Should I put current.setLeft(root) here?
        } else {
            parent = current;
            current.setRight(current);
        }
        // Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
        if (array[i].compareTo(parent.getData()) < 0) {
            parent.setLeft(new BSTNode(array[i]));
        } else {
            parent.setRight(new BSTNode(array[i]));
        }
        i++;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! @Maurice Perry Look much better!

Comment: `current.setLeft(current);` and `current.setRight(current);` basically link the current node to itself which can cause an endless loop. Those calls don't make sense at all. Try to explain what your intention is with this piece of code and it should become obvious what should happen. Additionally, you're never changing `current` in the loop and thus `parent` will also never change.

Comment: I see that why it kept loading. I try to make it turn left while 2 variable comparison <0 and turn right if >0. I researched some sample code they just simple put current.left or current.right. But it didn't work in my case so I thought setLeft would work. I don't know how to declare it in a correct way. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've initialized the `root`, you've already inserted the first element, so you can increment `i` right away.

You set the `left` and `right` pointers without keeping track of the prior value.

You never change the value of `current` within the loop, and, as you immediately assign it to `parent`, you don't change `parent` either.

You should return the `root` instead of the `current` node.

How about something like this:

```
    while (++i <= end) {
        current = root;
        while (current != null) {
            parent = current;
            if (array[i].compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
                current = current.getLeft();
            } else {
                current = current.getRight();
            }
        }
        // Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
        if (array[i].compareTo(parent.getData()) < 0) {
            parent.setLeft(new BSTNode(array[i]));
        } else {
            parent.setRight(new BSTNode(array[i]));
        }
    }
    return root;
```

UPDATE:

You can avoid a redundant comparison by keeping its result in a variable:

```
    while (++i <= end) {
        boolean left;
        current = root;
        do {
            parent = current;
            left = array[i].compareTo(current.getData()) < 0;
            if (left) {
                current = current.getLeft();
            } else {
                current = current.getRight();
            }
        } while (current != null);
        // Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
        if (left) {
            parent.setLeft(new BSTNode(array[i]));
        } else {
            parent.setRight(new BSTNode(array[i]));
        }
    }
    return root;
```

Comment: Note that you should also check that `start <= end` at the beginning, and return `null` otherwise.

Comment: `start` and `end` are both inclusive actually (I would rather have `end` exclusive, but it's not in the question.)

Comment: @sadetaosa please read my answer before posting comments

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It really helpful to me!. I'll test it tmr and will update if it runs well!

Comment: On a side note, the entire loop body is basically just the `add(value)` method, i.e. you could move that code to a separate method and then just call it like `add(array[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Main {

    public static final class Node {

        public static final String NULL = "_";
        public static final String SPLIT = ",";

        private final String val;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        public Node(String val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Node root = createBinaryTree();
        String str = serialize(root);   // 0,1,3,7,_,9,_,_,_,4,_,_,2,5,_,8,_,_,6,_,_
        Node newRoot = deserialize(str);
    }

    private static String serialize(Node root) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        serialize(root, buf);
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private static void serialize(Node node, StringBuilder buf) {
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append(Node.SPLIT);

        if (node == null)
            buf.append(Node.NULL);
        else {
            buf.append(node.val);
            serialize(node.left, buf);
            serialize(node.right, buf);
        }
    }

    private static Node deserialize(String str) {
        String[] values = str.split(Node.SPLIT);
        return deserialize(values, new AtomicInteger());
    }

    private static Node deserialize(String[] values, AtomicInteger i) {
        if (i.get() >= values.length)
            return null;

        String value = values[i.getAndIncrement()];

        if (Node.NULL.equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            return null;

        Node node = new Node(value);
        node.left = deserialize(values, i);
        node.right = deserialize(values, i);

        return node;

    }

    /*
     *         0
     *       /  \
     *      1    2
     *     / \  / \
     *    3  4 5  6
     *   /      \
     *  7        8
     *   \
     *    9
     */
    private static Node createBinaryTree() {
        Node[] nodes = { new Node("0"), new Node("1"), new Node("2"), new Node("3"),
                new Node("4"), new Node("5"), new Node("6"), new Node("7"),
                new Node("8"), new Node("9") };

        nodes[0].left = nodes[1];
        nodes[0].right = nodes[2];
        nodes[1].left = nodes[3];
        nodes[1].right = nodes[4];
        nodes[2].left = nodes[5];
        nodes[2].right = nodes[6];
        nodes[3].left = nodes[7];
        nodes[5].right = nodes[8];
        nodes[7].right = nodes[9];

        return nodes[0];
    }


}
```